# Spring+SiteMesh 2.0 Chinese character support

Tags: spring-mvc, encoding, sitemesh

I use spring3.0 and sitemesh2.0.The issue is am not able to display chinese characters in my jsp page.

I have done the following

web.xml

```
<filter>     
        <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>     
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>     
        <init-param>         
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>         
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>     
        </init-param> 
        <init-param>             
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>             
            <param-value>true</param-value>         
        </init-param> 
    </filter>  
    <filter-mapping>     
        <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>     
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern> 
    </filter-mapping> 
    <filter>
```

In my jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

In sitemesh template:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

sitemesh.xml:

```
<sitemesh>
    <property name="decorators-file" value="/WEB-INF/decorators.xml" />
    <excludes file="${decorators-file}" />

    <page-parsers>
        <parser content-type="text/html"
            class="com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.parser.HTMLPageParser" />
        <parser content-type="text/html;charset=UTF-8"
            class="com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.parser.HTMLPageParser" />
    </page-parsers>

    <decorator-mappers>
        <mapper class="com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.mapper.ConfigDecoratorMapper">
            <param name="config" value="${decorators-file}" />
        </mapper>
    </decorator-mappers>
</sitemesh>
```

But still the chinese characters are displayed like this:
å®å¾½çä½³å®ç©å·(éå¢)æéå¬å¸

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reply is kinda late but I hope someone else might benefit from what I wasted hours on. Spring's filter didn't work for me either. I wrote my own and set servletResponse's contentType manually. I have no problems right now.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    chain.doFilter(req, resp);
}

<filter>
    <filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.muratdozen.mvc.filters.EncodingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/ui/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/views/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was how i solved it. <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher> did the trick

Answer (score 2):

Your filter and jsp both look fine. Maybe check database settings as well.
Also bear in mind when you connect to your db, you need to specify `characterEncoding`:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourdb?characterEncoding=UTF-8
```